# Listing required Azure container files/file types using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have two azure containers. One filled with lot of files and other is new container. With Azure storage explorer, the container with lot files does not work as it hangs due to large data in it. I would like to see the files of my interest using Powershell and move them to new container.

`Get-AzureStorageBlob  -Container $container -Context $destContext` lists all the blobs which is not practically good option  as it is difficult to search all blobs as data is huge.

I want to search say for example only .csv files or .txt files or search with part of name using "Powershell". How can it be done?

Note:

I tried to use

```
Get-ChildItem Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container -Context $destContext | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*.csv"}
```

But this did not work.

Could you please help me to achieve this using Powershell?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
get-azurestorageblob -Container test -blob *.csv
```

That will get you a list of all the csv files in the container.

The REST API itself doesn't support filtering server side beyond the concept of a prefix.  You can pass a -Prefix parameter and on the server it will scope the results down to only BLOBs that start with that prefix.  This is most often done to get all the BLOBs that reside in the same "folder" on a container (note folders aren't really supported in BLOB storage, the "path" is just part of the BLOB name).

Comment: On a side note, the free Azure Explorer from Cerebrata (that I work for) has a search functionality which can do this as well if you need more one off type lookups and not automation.

Comment: Thank you.I find the above command in powershell too slow.It almost returns no value!

Comment: I am finding tool useful though.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the answer.  There is no way to ask the REST service to filter based on file type, thus the call brings back ALL of the BLOBs in the container and then client side does the filtering.  You can filter by prefix on the server (using the -prefix parameter), but that won't help you here unless you reorganize how you store the files which may not be useful at all.

Comment: Yeah..that's correct...This is one drawback currently we have in PowerShell. I will have to look for some other way.
Thank you!

Comment: You need to pass the context as well for this to work, so:
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName FunkyStorage -StorageAccountKey {Enter your storage account key here}
get-azurestorageblob -Container test -blob *.csv -Context $context